# Can moderators preemptively add tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

The tag synonym suggestion system open to regular users only allows suggesting as synonyms tags that are already being used. Broadly speaking, that looks like a reasonable restriction, as it makes it harder to create synonyms just for the sake of it, without a demonstrated need. Still, I wonder if moderators have the power to bypass the restriction and create tag synonyms out of nothing, and if there is any precedent applicable to that issue (thus far I didn't manage to unearth anything of the sort).

(A possible use case for preemptive synonyms I can think of involves lower volume tags borne out of burninations and disambiguations. In such cases, a carefully chosen synonym, ideally shaped through a meta discussion with interested users, might help with discoverability through tag auto-completion. This could be a silly idea, of course -- I'm only mentioning it so that you don't think I'm asking on a whim.)

Comment: As long as a real target "tag" exists - mods can syn. things to it without that syn. already existing as a tag by itself.

Comment: @JonClements Interesting, thanks. I presume you'd need to make a pretty strong case to persuade mods to do that, right? (I was in part trying to gauge that by asking about precedents.)

Comment: Yes... The whole synonym system has quirks as to how it works and I'm not aware of any precedent for it to be required preemptively. Heck, we might end tripping ourselves up in a non-obvious way doing so (think of cases where one might guess "this-tag" is convenient for "that-tag" and then "this-tag" becomes a popular library and no-one can ask about "this-tag" by itself because it just gets silently renamed kind of thing). Might want to have a look on MSE - think this has come up before in one way or another?

Comment: @JonClements There doesn't seem to be anything near the surface in MSE -- thus far, all I found was [a small handful of other moderator powers involving synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities+tag-synonyms), and [a related feature request tucked away in an answer from 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58756/242059).

Comment: You could always just add the tag you feel needs to be a synonym to an existing Q, suggest the syn. et voila.

Comment: @Luuklag I had considered that option, but the thought of adding a tag of dubious usefulness to a question gave me pause, specially because in lower volume tags it might take long to get it approved without moderator intervention.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Preemptive tag synonyms are possible for moderators. We can spin up new tags whenever it is required. For example, I added a [tan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tan) as a synonym for [the trignometry tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/trigonometry/synonyms), because [cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cos) and [sine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sine) were synonymized to it. Just for demonstration, I added another new tag to it, [mso-385707](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mso-385707):

> [image: Screenshot of tag synonyms for trigonometry]

Let us know if you need to preemptively add a new synonym by creating a meta post.

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't also create and synonymize `tangent` when you did tan?

Comment: Good to know the possibility exists. Thanks.

Comment: @TylerH, that is _tangent_ ial to this discussion. ;p ... (I didn't add [tangent] because, no one was using [tan], so I assumed that no one would be using [tangent])

Comment: i want to know what mso-385707 is for!

Comment: The question ID, @DanielA.White.

Comment: @BhargavRao Oh, you *didn't* add [tan]? Your answer says "I added [tan]" which suggests otherwise.