# Should I create a tag, then make it a synonym right after?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I want to create [cpluslus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpluslus) to be a synonym of [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), but it says that I have to create the tag first.

So should I do it?

To clarify, what I want to do is just to make the tag cover more broadly

Comment: For what reason?

Comment: @JeanneDark well, to make it more documented. Maybe someone's keyboard doesn't have a `+` symbol.

Comment: Related: [Can moderators preemptively add tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385707/11682469)

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a collaborative effort. You should never reason from the perspective of what *you* want, you should always reason from the perspective of *what do my peers want*. The most important signal here is that even today in 2021 there is no tag named cplusplus. I can assure you that this is not because everyone just through epic coincidence completely forgot about it.

Comment: @justANewbie *Maybe someone's keyboard doesn't have a + symbol.* [`c++` has two synonyms `cpp` and `cxx`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/synonyms)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no need whatsoever for this synonym, or the correctly-spelled [cplusplus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cplusplus). So, no, you should not do it.

While it is *possible* for moderators to preemptively create synonyms, we do not do it routinely. Synonyms need only exist when there is a legitimate need for them (*e.g.*, a tag has been renamed or merged, and we want to avoid breaking users' bookmarks). Considering that in the past decade or more that Stack Overflow has been around, we have never needed this synonym, I don't think the need has suddenly become any more pressing.

Nobody programming in C++ manages to do so without a plus key on their keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just earned my brand new privilege, and just want to test it (and that `+`  is a joke :-) )

Comment: Tag creation is not a very fun or useful privilege. Most of the tags that need to exist here already *do* exist, save perhaps for the release of some brand-new library or other tech. Don't get too eager to use them.

Comment: "Nobody programming in C++ manages to do so without a plus key on their keyboard." I thought about suggesting a trigraph, but there is no trigraph for plus sign.

Comment: You think I don't consider what pedantic comments people might make *before* posting on the Meta site, @TadeuszKopec?